# WPF. Скрыть в трей при закрытии окна по крестику

Tags: c#, wpf

Помогите сделать скрытие окна при нажатии на крестик.
Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
private void OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{           
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Hide();
    base.OnClosing(e);           
}
```

Но это вызывается бесконечно много раз и вываливается StackOverflowException.
Вероятно нужно отписать от какого-то события. Как понять от какого?

Вот так вроде работает, окно исчезает, но иконки нет в трее. ЕЕ нужно добавить?

```
private void OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
}
```

Comment: @Андрей NOP Имя "TaskbarIcon" не существует в пространстве имен "http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar".

Comment: Блин, установить пакет нужно ))

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ @ДмитрийСуворов